# Videos has no picture, but VLC works

Tags: videos, codec, release-jolnir

Videos app has sound but no picture. VLC however works on the same file just fine.

I have already done:

```
sudo apt install -y ubuntu-restricted-extras libavcodec-extra libdvd-pkg
```

Yes, I know, the answer is use VLC, but it would be nice to get this fixed.  My best guess is Videos on 6.1 is not finding any codecs at all.  These are stock standard .mp4 format files.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Same problem. Black screen with sounds. "ubuntu-restricted-extras" have been installed. I had solved the problem by reinstalling videos, but now it doesn't work.

Comment: Just saw this, has it been resolved? I would also like to use the default player.

Comment: Never resolved.